# Breakpoints Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I need some help with collapse nav bar.
On smaller devices it works fine, but tablet portrait as there are too many links in the menu the nav breaks, how do I get the collapse nav to show on tablet devices too.

I don't use LESS and I've read the docs on BS customize page, but did not understand what fields to change:

1. @grid-float-breakpoint-max

   ```
   What do I add here... 

   Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
   ```
2. @grid-float-breakpoint

   ```
   What do I add here... 

   Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
   ```

Any help would he appreciated.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using LESS and don't want to customize your Bootstrap build, you can use a CSS media query to override the collapse breakpoint. Just make sure this CSS follows the `bootstrap.css`..

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/105915

Comment: You've been able to re-use this answer the last couple days... ;)

Comment: I know it. Seems like there is a question everyday about the navbar breakpoint!

Comment: And all worded slightly different so they don't show up in the OP's previous searches...

Comment: Thank you @Skelly! I've added this code to my custom style sheet, which is placed below BS style sheet. The issue is the collapse nav opens and closes instantly, i.e. will not stay open.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define `@grid-float-breakpoint-max`; by default, it's auto-calculated from `@grid-float-breakpoint`.

If the user's viewport (which, oversimplifying a bit, is their screen) is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width, then the navbar will be displayed uncollapsed (i.e. the navbar items will be displayed in a horizontal row). If the viewport is narrower than that, then the navbar will be collapsed into a togglable menu that displays the navbar items vertically.

Comment: Thank you @cvrebert, in the field (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1) do I just replace the 1 with a break point?

Comment: You shouldn't modify that field (which is for `@grid-float-breakpoint-max`) at all.

Comment: @user2202463 If this answer was satisfactory to you, could you please mark it as accepted? Would greatly appreciate that.